# Roundcube: set hostname for system users

Tags: roundcube

I've roundcube, devocot and postfix correctly configurated. Virtual users can connect with roundcube with own full email and password:

```
test00@domain.org
```

system users can connect only without domain name and authentication works but in identity I see:

```
user<>
```

without hostname of server

I tried to add this line but doesn't work:

```
$rcmail_config['mail_domain'] = '%d';
```

and I've same problem

Comment: Are you talking about sent emails or the display of the own name in roundcube itself?

Comment: In above on the right I don't see any username, in postfix log I see "user<>" without any system domain name. Only virtual users after connect see user and domain name

Comment: So you are talking about the postfix logs, not roundcube?